# Swift define datatype of array

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, iteration

I need to somehow cast a 2dimensional array...
console:

```
solution.swift:22:23: error: missing argument label 'arr:' in call
array = invertArr(arr)
                  ^
                  arr: 
 solution.swift:53:12: error: cannot convert return expression of type '[[Any]]' to return type '[[Int]]'
return result
       ^~~~~~
              as! [[Int]]
```

and that's the code:

```
func invertArr(arr:[[Int]]) -> [[Int]]{
var counter = 0
var result = [[]]
for element in arr{
    if counter == 0{
        continue
    }
    var counter2 = 0
    for item in element.reversed(){
        result[counter][counter2] = item
        counter2 += 1
    }
    counter += 1
}
return result
}
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Simple compilation errors, 1) name of argument must be included in call `array = invertArr(arr: arr)`2) You need to define the type (and initialise) `var result = [[Int]]()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of two serious issues your code cannot work anyway even if you call the method with the `arr` parameter label and declare result as `[[Int]]()`.

- As `counter` is 0 the first loop `continue`s always and an empty array is returned.
- `result[counter][counter2] = item` crashes reliably because there are no items at the given indices.

To invert the order of the items in the inner arrays this is a generic version

```
func invertArr<T>(arr: [[T]]) -> [[T]]{
    var result = arr
    for (index, element) in arr.enumerated() {
        result[index] = element.reversed()
    }
    return result
}

let array = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
let inverted = invertArr(arr: array) // [[4, 3, 2, 1], [8, 7, 6, 5]]
```

If you want to reverse also the items in the outer array `return result.reversed()`